# Unable to update EditText from AsyncTask and an infinite loop

Tags: java, android, sockets, loops, android-asynctask

I have the following problem. On the main thread I have an `EditText` field, I have an `AsyncTask` which infinitely listens to a socket for incoming messages. In the loop (located in `doInBackground()`) I'm trying to call the `onProgressUpdate()` and to pass it a string and I want when the oPU() receive the string to display it on the `EditText` placed at the main thread.

```
  public class ClientSide extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
  public EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bar1);
  ...}
```

The first problem is the on `findViewById(R.id.bar1)` it says cannot resolve symbol. What may cause it, how can I fix it. 
The second issue is with the loop. The problem is that I don't want to periodically create new `AsyncTask` object through the main thread as in my case it means to create a socket and bind to it each time the object is .execute()-ed. Please, suggest me a way to reorganize my code so that to make the solution of that more elegant. I know that `AsyncTasks` are for short processes not app-long so I understand that my current solution (with the loop) is a decomposing carrot (a.k.a. bad one). 
Once again:
 1. How to make `findViewById()` to really match the `EditText` UI element?
 2. How to reorganize my code in order to not create sockets each time when the app needs to perform its message listener on background?

You can see the Async.. doInBackground as well:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params){

    final String SERVER_HOSTNAME = "hereGoesMyIP";
    final int SERVER_PORT = 2002;
    BufferedReader mSocketReader;
    PrintWriter mSocketWriter;
    final String TAG = ClientSide.class.getSimpleName();
    String outputln = "Me. Android";


    try {
        //Initialization of the socket, socket reader and writer.
        Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_HOSTNAME, SERVER_PORT);
        mSocketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        mSocketWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        System.out.println("Connected to server " + SERVER_HOSTNAME + ":" + SERVER_PORT);


        //An infinite loop which checks for incoming messages.
        while(true){
            String inMsg="";
            String aMessage = "";

            //Reads from the socket
            if((inMsg=mSocketReader.readLine())!=null && socket.isConnected()){
                publishProgress(inMsg);
            }

            Thread.sleep(500);//still requres try - catch?
        }


    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Cannot connect to " + SERVER_HOSTNAME + ":" + SERVER_PORT);
        ioe.printStackTrace();

    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)`findViewByid()` is a  method avialable in Activity class . it's not avialable in AsyncTask class. So pass your view to AsyncTask Like this

```
 private Context mContext;
private View yourView;


    public Clientside(Context context, View rootView){
        this.mContext=context;
        this.yourView=rootView;
    }
```

Then you can acess it like this

```
EditText editText = yourView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

Remember you cannot update your view from a background thread so use `progressupdate()` or `postExecute()` method to update your EditText which runs on main thread.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

}


  View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();//This will return you the rootView



ClientSide cs = new ClientSide(getApplicationContext(),rootView);//do this in your mainactivity
```

**getApplicationContext() will return you the Context you are in.**

ThankYou. I hope this was helpful.

Comment: thank you so much for the so detailed answer. I'm testing now your solution. If you have anything about 2) I'll be glad to... read it. Thank you so much once again. I hope to check your answer as a best. Just give me 1-2 minutes to run that...

Comment: 2) one i could understand your question

Comment: can you please explain me your second question?

Comment: it was about how to make a socket only once and pass it to the AsyncTask. This way in the Async I'll do only listener and I'll call the asynchronous thread periodically from the main thread and thus I'll avoid the infinite loop within the Async. Currently the program does the opposite - calls the Async once and then creates a socket once (ok) but has an infinite loop which I think is the worst solution. I know that Asyncs are for short processes not for app-long, from this point of view 'the worst'

Comment: If thats's what you want. Then create a socket in your mainThread and pass it your constructor like we did with view. This may solve your problem. ThankYou

Comment: Do i deserve any vote again?? haha . You are welcome

Comment: sorry my friend, seems like I am too noobie, I've stuck for last time, I swear... SO, everything is fine except from how to get the context and how -//- the View from the main thread. I have just that >>>> `EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textF);` and a onClick which roughly does `new ClientSide(xxxxx,xxxxxxx).execute();`. According to your code on the place of x-es I've to give it the Context as well as View. The EditText I made through the GUI env. of Andr. Studio. Sorry for me being so annoying, I hope its the last time. How to get context and View then?

Comment: mission accomplished, thank you so much, immensely sorry for the taken time, you were great!

Comment: I've voted... see, your answer is with the green tick as well as +1 point. The app crashes like a viking but that's another story :D :D :D

Comment: Hey if you have any doubts or query's you can contact me @ joissumanth@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

I believe to stop this issue you will have to refresh the EditText inside **onProgressUpdate**

for example :

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String newText) {
  field.setText(newText);
  field.invalidate();  
}
```

and declare the field variable outside on main thread..not inside your client side class..

this onProgressUpdate(..) is inside your ClientSide..

Comment: `field` is `cannot resolve symbol` as well... that won't work.

Comment: @KDX2 yea sorry about that..i forgot to see that..jois way of creating view.findViewById is more better i believe..